# Weight of marbles in a bag

Tags: prolog, logic

So we just started learning prolog and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around prolog. We had this problem for homework and I just have no idea where to start.

Define a rule `weight(R, O, Y, G, B)` to find out how many marbles of each color can be contained in each bag, where `R, O, Y, G`, and `B` are the number of red, orange, yellow, green, blue marbles, respectively. The weight of the marbles is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` grams respectively. Assuming the size of the bag is big enough to hold all the marbles with the total weight of `30` grams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were going to solve this problem for just (say) yellow marbles, it would probably look like this:

```
weight(Marbles, Weight) :- Weight #= Marbles * 3.
```

Then if you wanted to see how many yellow marbles you have, you would query Prolog like so:

```
?- weight(Marbles, 30).
Marbles = 10.
```

Can you generalize from here? :)

**Edit**

Your problem can be solved by providing a domain.

```
weight(R,O,Y,G,B,Weight) :- 
    [R,O,Y,G,B] ins 0..sup, 
    Weight #= R + O*2 + Y*3 + G*4 + B*5.
```

When you call the predicate, you will get answers in the form of domains. This is usually not what I expect, so calling `label/1` will generate solutions.

```
?- weight(R,O,Y,G,B,30), label([R,O,Y,G,B]).
R = O, O = Y, Y = G, G = 0,                 
B = 6 ;                                     

R = O, O = Y, Y = 0,                        
G = 5,                                      
B = 2 ;
```

etc.

Comment: Well i originally tried something like weight(R,O,Y,G,B,W) : W  #= R + O*2 + Y*3 + G*4 + B*5. The problem is if I query(R,O,1,1,1,30) i get an installation error. And I need to be able to do that.

Comment: The domain is what i was missing. Thank you. I knew the general idea behind the problem, I just had no idea how to generate all possible solutions. I was just missing the domain.

Comment: "for labels"? Never heard that. Either labeling, or enumeration.

Comment: Would there be a way to do it without the labeling and domain.

Comment: Possibly. I'm far from a clpfd expert. :) But the "fd" does stand for "finite domain" so I am not convinced you can escape from defining the domain. You could of course try and figure it out without using clpfd at all, but I think you will find it taxing. This is a great example of when it should be used.

Comment: @false if I omit the labeling step, SWI gives me back domains rather than values. `labels` enumerates solutions. You know much more about clpfd than me, so whatever semantic issue you actually have, please spell it out for me.

Comment: My comment was just on the wording "for labels". Nothing deeper. Asking for labeling. Or even better: simply enumerating solutions (which are ground)  vs. getting answers (that might not contain a solution at all)